# Локальное хранение данных с сервера

Tags: java, android, activity, хранение-данных

Есть активити, в которой могут переключаться фрагменты. При переключении фрагмента должен меняться title у активити. При старте активити на сервер посылается запрос и приходит список этих тайтлов. Проблема в том, что когда пришел ответ с сервера их нужно где-то хранить локально списком, чтобы потом менять тайтл на значения из этого списка. Вопрос-где и как лучше его хранить, чтобы это было корректно и не пользоваться костылями

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если данный список должен храниться в приложении всегда, т.е. даже когда интернета нет и приложение запускают, а этот список нужен, то ваш выбор это База Данных или `SharedPreferences`.

Я так понимаю, этот список - обычный список строк, значит для него база будет излишней, используйте `SharedPreferences`. Если же потом эти тайтлы расширятся до объектов, в которых есть поле `title` то используйте БД с перспективой на будущее.

Если же тайтлы при запуске всегда должны приходить из сети, то храните просто в поле класса. Активити или адаптера (если речь про `ViewPager`) или презентера. Смотря что у вас отвечает за логику. И не забывайте записывать этот список в `SavedInstanceState`. Чтобы при поворотах он не терялся